# Formatting date correctly

Tags: java, android, string, date

Hello ***`stackoverflowers`***, Let's say i have a database with a row filled with dates, Okay?

### Problem 1:

**Like this one :**

2013-06-01

So i want to translate this date to String

**Input:**

Tue Mar 01 00:00:00 EET 2013

As an example.. 
 So how can i turn the output of the date  like this:

Mar 2013 ??
Here's my codes:

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH)
                            .parse(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_AVAILABILITYDATE)));
                    list.add(date);
```

### Problem 2(Problem 1 must be solved first i guess):

Of course i want to sort the list i added the date to.

So i run this code:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

But frankly  it doesn't sort correctly! it's mixed - dates all wrongs.

Thanks for reading, i hope it's easy!

### All Codes:

```
public ArrayList<Date> GetValues() {
ArrayList<Date> list = new ArrayList<Date>();
        Date date;
if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                try {
                    date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH)
                            .parse(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_AVAILABILITYDATE)));
                    list.add(date);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mCursor.moveToNext();
            }

        }

        Collections.sort(list);

        return list;

    }
```

After loosing some hope i decided to show you all codes:

### Codes:

```
    Database DbHelper = new Database(
                    this.getSherlockActivity()).open();
            ArrayList<Date> headers = DbHelper.GetValues();

            HashSet<Date> hs = new HashSet<Date>();
            hs.addAll(headers);
            headers.clear();
            headers.addAll(hs);
                    Collections.sort(header,dateComparator);
            Collections.reverse(headers);
```

I'm using 3rd party library :  [StickyGridHeadersGridView](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) so here's my adapter:

```
@Override
public int getCountForHeader(int header) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

    @Override
    public int getNumHeaders() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return headers.size();
    }

    @Override
public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
        TextView tvheader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvheader);
        String headertitle = headers.get(position).toString();
        if (headertitle.contains("01 00:00:00 EET")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("01 00:00:00 EET", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("01 00:00:00 EEST")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("01 00:00:00 EEST", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("02 00:00:00 EET")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("02 00:00:00 EET", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("02 00:00:00 EEST")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("02 00:00:00 EEST", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("15 00:00:00 EET")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("15 00:00:00 EET", "");
        }
        // days
        if (headertitle.contains("Mon")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Mon", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Tue")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Tue", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Wed")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Wed", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Thu")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Thu", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Fri")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Fri", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Sat")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Sat", "");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Sun")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Sun", "");
        }

        // months
        if (headertitle.contains("Jan")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Jan", "January");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Feb")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Feb", "February");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Mar")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Mar", "March");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Apr")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Apr", "April");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Jun")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Jun", "June");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Jul")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Jul", "July");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Aug")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Aug", "August");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Sep")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Sep", "September");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Oct")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Oct", "October");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Nov")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Nov", "November");
        }
        if (headertitle.contains("Dec")) {
            headertitle = headertitle.replace("Dec", "December");
        }
        tvheader.setText(headertitle);

    }
```

However now the results are all mixed up and lost! the gridview is big and i only see :

### September 2013 June 2013 July 2013

in each row. What can i do ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need to build a comparator to compare two dates:

here is a code for it:

```
public static Comparator<Date> dateComparator = new Comparator<Date>()
{
    public int compare(Date date1, Date date2)
    {
        return date1.compareTo(date2);
    }
};
```

and you can call it using this line of code:

```
Collections.sort(list,dateComparator);
```

and this is how to use arrays instead of collections

```
Date[] arrayDates = new Date[list.size()];
arrayDates = list.toArray(arrayDates);
Arrays.sort(arrayDates, dateComparator);
```

Comment: the collections will do this for you, and your list will be sorted.
just fill the list and call the last line.

Comment: While the codes are different, i got a different output but NOT ordered correctly at all

Comment: there is no way that comparator will give you wrong result if you use the right compare statement. another way to do it is to use arrays instead of collections, just to make sure

Comment: Where do i add that code ? 
Collections.sort(list,dateComparator);

inside the loop or outside?

Comment: out side the loop, and because you are passing reference, of course it will re-arrange your list.

Answer (score 1):

So after 1 day of `contuniously` working on a fix, i have found out that the problem occured from `GridViewStickyHeaders` - external library.

The problem occurs once i scroll! the results all get messed.

Thanks for your contribution! your help really helped me! thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `"MMM yyyy"` as your regex, like so:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(format.format(now));
  }
}
```

`> Sep 2013`

2) Using a comparator with `compareTo()` shouldn't be necessary since `Collections.sort(list)` should sort a list of Dates chronologically by default.

Most likely, the problem lies somewhere in the code you're not showing but I can't be sure since you're not mocking the database so I can't run your code in Eclipse.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html